# How to integrate AWS Cognito federated identities in a production environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to integrate a solution for user authentication and authorization in a serverless web application that uses Api gateway and is exposed to customers. Users login through Cognito user pools and obtain temporary AWS access keys through Cognito federated identities, which are then used by the frontend client to perform signed requests to the API. I also use role mapping to map user claims to IAM roles.

The application needs to perform operations that involve users. For instance:

1. It should be able to assign users to groups. For that there is a Dynamo table that uses a federated identity id as Hash key. That becomes problematic in terms of being able to backup the federated identity data, because the identity ids are auto-generated and not in my control. Therefore if I lose the identity pool, even if I can restore the datasets from a backup, those hash keys in the dynamo table will end up pointing to resources that do not exist anymore because the identity ids would have been regenerated. A way to solve that would be to include in each dataset a "uuid" key-value pair that would be populated manually. Even though federated identities do not have a trigger on identity creation so a workaround would be required. Also, because there is no way to find out the Cognito user pool entry associated to a given identity without having the user's access token I would not be able to reattach identities to their respective Cognito users.
2. Users should be able to create resources, and when those resources are displayed in the UI they should contain its creator's username. Because that data (the username) is stored in the Cognito user pool and there is no way to obtain it given an identity id, I would have to include the user's JWT access token containing his data and claims in the requests to my API, and then validate and decode it every time. Having this additional authorization logic seems to beat the purpose of the authorization via temporary AWS credentials.

This makes me wonder if I am just trying to use the federation functionality for a use case it is not designed for. Even though I always found very appealing the ability to have a unified way of controlling access to all AWS resources, including custom serverless endpoints.

Is my understanding wrong about how it works or is it really a case of "not the right tool for the job"?